# SQL Server : how to replace from string based on next chars

Tags: sql-server

```
 Declare @string nvarchar (400) ='5 kg/ 8 s/ m/ 9 l/ o'
```

I need replace all occurrences of `/` only where next char is not a number to `/1~`

Result should be

```
5 kg/ 8 s/1~m/ 9 l/1~o
```

is there any short way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason you try to do this in the database? SQL Server has no regular expressions and it's far easier to do this with regex on the client.

Comment: I agree with @Panagiotis ! one_up for him!

Comment: ya i am creating a unit conversion function from string for batch. where if there is no number entered before unit name just to automatically insert 1 before unit name

Comment: SQL Server does not support regular expressions directly. You can use CLR, here are some examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlclr/archive/2005/06/29/regex.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar (400) ='5 kg/ 8 s/ m/ 9 l/ o'
DECLARE @result nvarchar(400)= '' 

SELECT @result += '/' +case when t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)') not like ' [0-9]%' 
  then stuff(t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)'), 1,1, '1~') 
  else t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)') end
FROM (
    SELECT x = CAST('<t>' + 
          REPLACE(' '+@string, '/', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
) a
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c)

SELECT stuff(@result, 1,2,'')
```

Result:

```
5 kg/ 8 s/1~m/ 9 l/1~o
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do something in these lines

Declare @string nvarchar (400) ='5 kg/ 8 s/ m/ 9 l/ o'
DECLARE @stringLength INT
SELECT @stringLength = LEN(@string)

DECLARE @counter INT
SELECT @counter = 1

WHILE @counter <= @stringlength
BEGIN

DECLARE @currentChar VARCHAR(1)
SELECT @currentChar = SUBSTRING ( @string ,@counter , 1 )

IF(@counter < @stringlength)
BEGIN
DECLARE @nextChar VARCHAR(1)
SELECT @nextChar = SUBSTRING ( @string ,@counter + 1 , 1 )

PRINT 'Current ' + @currentChar
PRINT 'Next '  + @nextChar
PRINT ' -- '

end

SET @counter = @counter + 1

END

What I am doing to looping each character of the string and checking current and next character. From here onwards you have the index of the character from within the string, and you can execute a replace if the next character is a "/". Should not be too complicated but you got the idea of how it can be implemented.